# Why does my ajax request show error then disappear immediately from firebug console?

Tags: javascript

I am using ajax to submit form (which is in bootstrap modal) data so after from submit in firebug I error disappear immediately.

```
$('button#submit').click(function () {          
    var id = $('#id').val();
    var lang = $('#elang').val();
    var from = $('#from').val();        
    var to = $('#to').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    var file = $('#file').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://10.10.1.83/services/mail.php',
        data: {
            'from': from, 'to': to, 'id': id
        },
        success: function(msg) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Debug mode to do step by step and get time to see Error,

Comment: when you do submit click pause mark to stop and error will be showing,

Answer (score 0):

In developer tools, click the network tab, and make sure that "preserve log" is ticked.